# How to set CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE in curl?

Tags: c++, smtp, libcurl

I am unable to send mails with large data content.
While performing sending mail getting **segmentation fault**.
After googling found that setting CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE can solve the issue, but this couldn't set in my application.
I tried the below,

```
#ifdef CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE
#undef CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE
#define CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE 131072
#endif
```

And the callback function is

```
size_t mail_payload_source(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp ){
struct mail_upload_status *upload_ctx = (struct mail_upload_status *)userp;
const char *data;
if((size == 0) || (nmemb == 0) || ((size*nmemb) < 1)) {
  return 0;
}
data = mail_char_ary_of_pntrs[upload_ctx->lines_read];
if(data) {
    size_t len = strlen(data);
    memcpy(ptr, data, len);
    upload_ctx->lines_read++;
    return len;
}
return 0;}
```

Can anyone please suggest a workaround for this ?

Comment: There is not enough context for a potential answerer to figure out how to help you. How is your problem related to curl?

Comment: Getting segmentation fault on "res = curl_easy_perform(curl);"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by re-configuring with setting the value of `CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE` to a higher value.

Comment: don't copy more data to the destination buffer than what fits!